# Copy protected sheet permissions when copying a file within Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm tried to ensure protected sheets in Google Sheets have their permissions copied across to their copies when copying a folder, which contains Google Sheets.

When I copy a set of folders within Google Drive using any of the Copy Folder utilities in the Google Apps marketplace, none of them seems to copy the permissions for protected sheets in Google Sheets to their respective copies.

Background: I've noticed that if I copy a single Google Sheet from within the Google Drive explorer (not using a copy folder utility) the permissions aren't copied either. However, if I choose "Make a copy..." from the File menu within the Google Sheet, there is the option to choose "Share it with the same people", then the permissions of protected sheets are copied across to the new copy.

... So, I got in touch with Google support and they have told me that the API does support the individual permissions of protected sheets to be copied to the copy. Does anyone know if there are any utilities out their that have this support in their Copy Folder utilities? The details about this on the API is here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

I'd be most grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no function yet available to do what you want to achieve (which you have already said earlier). You can create a ticket asking for a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user) (if you find it valuable to make it as a part of API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having contacted the developer of Copy Folder (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-folder/kfbicpdhiofpicipfggljdhjokjblnhl), he kindly enhanced his script. Now it copies the protected sheets and/or protected ranges of any Google Sheet it encounters during the folder hierarchy.